# Does electric and magnetic field interact?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, interactions

Can electric field or magnetic field interact with an Electromagnetic radiation?
And can 2 electromagnetic radiations interact with each other?
Rather than the interference effect.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE! I think that this question shows [insufficient prior research](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question). Can you try mentioning some relevant things you're familiar with, to narrow it down to a conceptual difficulty we can help fix? If it helps, try doing some research using the word 'photon', and consider the fact that magnetic fields are created by moving charges.

Comment: Also, based on your phrasing, I would think that you're a bit confused about the nature of electromagnetic radiation and the relationship between electric fields, magnetic fields, and EM radiation. Try asking a question about those. It'll help you answer this question. But to partially answer this, [interaction between photons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics) is a big deal in particle physics. Under certain conditions, 2 photons of appropriately high frequencies can create an electron-positron pair, and that's just the most well-know phenomenon. There's much more.

Comment: The only correct approach is to write down the field equations and see what may change the field. Study this subject first. There is a domain of field strengths for which fields do not interact, but "add up" in the total field.

Comment: Please be a little bit more precise! Do you  mean a classical view or and quantum mechanics view using photons?

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Can electric or magnetic fields interact with an electromagnetic radiation?

- Electromagnetic radiation in terms of a classical interpretation is a combination of an electrical and magnetic field! Taking the classical **Maxwell equations** gives an explanation of how . The easiest way to see it is to look at the **Poynting Vector**.

$$ \mathbf{S} = \frac{1}{\mu_0} \mathbf{E} \times \mathbf{B} \\
u = \frac{1}{2}\! \left(\varepsilon_0 \mathbf{E}^2 + \frac{1}{\mu_0} \mathbf{B}^2\right)\!, \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = -  \nabla \cdot \mathbf{S} -\mathbf{J} \cdot \mathbf{E}.$$

The Poynting vector $\mathbf S$ represents the directional **energy flux** of an em-field. If the energy density $u$ (B and E field) changes in time, you got radiation and Joulsche's dissipation. This is what the last equation express.

- In case you mean: Can an em-radiation, interpreted as an amount of photons, interact with em fields, the answer is also yes. But it is much more difficult to explain, and you have to use a quantization version of Maxwell equations -->  **quantum-electrodynamics** (QED).

**2.** Can two radiation interact with each other?

Yes, QED, and especially **quantum field theory** (2nd quantization) shows a lot of such examples.

- For instance the superposition is violated for strong fields! That means:

$$\mathbf E \ne  \mathbf E_1 + \mathbf E_2$$

- Photon-photon scattering

You can find a good and short description on this [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/242289/198290).

Comment: In this answer I treat the two photon interaction ( contrasted to superposition of light beams, which are the non interacting part) https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/242184/probability-of-photon-to-photon-collision/242289#242289

Comment: @anna v: Thank you for this link, I will add it in my answer!